# Вызов хранимой процедуры

Tags: c#, sql, visual-basic

Есть код на VB.Таблица выводит данные. Возникла трудность переписать на CSharp.
Есть ХП в которую нужно передать параметры, после этого переписывается в другую таблицу.

```
Me.QueriesTableAdapter1.prAEO_Obr(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, ComboBox_KAGRP.SelectedValue,
    ComboBox_KSMEN.SelectedValue, Me.ComboBox_KOP.SelectedValue)
Me.AEO_inTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccountingDataSet_Tabl.AEO_in) '' обновление таблицы
```

Как переписать на c#

Пробовала так

```
string sqlStoredProcedure = "prAEO_Obr";
string agr = Request.QueryString["agr"].ToString();
string store = Request.QueryString["store"].ToString();
string shift = Request.QueryString["shift"].ToString();
string oper = Request.QueryString["oper"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStoredProcedure, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@KagrIn_Tmove",agr);//переделать под параметры
    command.Parameters.Add("@Kagr_Tobr",store);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Ksmen", shift);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Kop", oper);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Какие трудности то с этим? Вы что то пробовали? Какие то ошибки получали?

Comment: Не могу залить в gridview, в gridview запрос на ту таблицу временную которая описана в ХП

Comment: в смысле вы не можете считать результат хранимой процедуры, я верно понял?

Comment: Да это так, gridview пуст

Comment: Откуда взялся gridview? В вопросе про это ничего нет

Comment: Забыла указать.

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы делаете. Вы используете table adapter и датасеты? Тогда вам [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Ну для начала `var result = command.ExecuteScalar();` это используется, когда нужно вернуть единственное значение. Для возврата таблиц или набора таблиц используется `var reader = command.ExecuteReader();`. Далее вы можете заполнять DataTable или DataSet из ридера, передав его в соответствующие методы в качестве параметра.